# What is this kind of shower diverter called?

Tags: plumbing, shower

I got two different Pfister style shower remodel kits. Everything is working fine except the diverter is not working at all. [image: Diverters]

The old one on the left works but sticks out too far for the handles and flanges I got. The two new ones do not work, presumably because of how they look near the top of the picture. How can I find a diverter that is short enough (4 1/4”) and has the right end on it?

Comment: Could we get a pic down the throat of the valve and exactly where you are measuring for the 4.5 inches and what is causing the original to be to big please.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you can't find a part number or identify the manufacturer on your old stem/cartdridge?

Looks like you'll have to browse through catalogs like this [one](https://content.interlinebrands.com/product/document/10145/133938_Brochure.pdf) and manually find the replacement. If you have the rebuild kit number you can search with Ctrl+F to go faster. Most of the time I just call/email the manufacturer of the new part and they end up finding the part for me.

Hope this helps a little bit.